# About javascript delay

Tags: javascript, delay

So I have a timer, a javascript code and a php file, my php file simply generating a code on the server side.

My JS code is running the code after my timer hits 1 seconds.

```
  timeleft = 120,
  ms = 1000;

var timerinterval;
var socket = io.connect('http://x:3333');

  if ($('.run #timeleft').size() > 0) {
    socket.on('timer', function(data) {
      timeleft = data.timeleft;
      if (timeleft == 1) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "generate.php",
            success: function(msg) {
              $('.code').before(msg);
            }
          });
        }, 3500);
      }
    });
    setInterval(updatetimer, 1);
  }


function updatetimer() {
  var n = 99 - Math.round((new Date()).getMilliseconds() / 10);
  if (timeleft == 120) {
    n = 0;
  }
  if (n < 0) {
    n = 0;
  }
  if (timeleft <= 0) {
    n = 0;
  }
  if (timeleft < 0) {
    timeleft = 0;
  }
  $('.run #timeleft').html(timeleft + ((n < 10) ? '.0' : '.') + n);
}
```

But the problem is sometimes my JS code pushes the old generated code. So I am having a timing issue here.

As I've analyzed, the timeout function gets the code from generate.php before timing out however it is running the code after 3 seconds. So this is causing bugs. The logic is there should be, getting code from generate.php after 3 seconds, not like get it and wait for 3 seconds to push it.

What I need is getting the generate.php code after 3 seconds *to make sure it won't get the old generated code once again*.

Comment: Try this: `setTimeout(function(){ $('.code').before(msg); },3000)`

Comment: I think you are confusing a few things. Could you show us the code around the code posted? I'd like to understand how you set `time`. What it currently says: if `time == 1` then wait 3 seconds (and do nothing while waiting) and then execute the ajax call

Comment: Alright, I just edit the code. Should be more specific.

Comment: did you try `async`:'false'?

Comment: Just tried it out and it didn't help either. As I mentioned I really think that it is timing issue. Generate.php is a file which contains same information until it gets runned again. And the js code calls it early. So it shows the oldest one before it generates the latest one. Because generating a new code and running it happens in same second, so I don't really know what to do since timeout function isn't working as well. :(

Answer (score 1):

you could try setting `cache`  within your ajax request to `false`:-

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "generate.php",
    cache: false, 
    success: function(msg) {
      $('.code').before(msg);
    }
});
```

[**API**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

> **cache** (default: true, false for dataType 'script' and 'jsonp')
>
> Type: Boolean
>
> If set to false, it will force requested pages not to be cached by the
>   browser. Note: Setting cache to false will only work correctly with
>   HEAD and GET requests. It works by appending "_={timestamp}" to the
>   GET parameters. The parameter is not needed for other types of
>   requests, except in IE8 when a POST is made to a URL that has already
>   been requested by a GET.

Comment: nice, didn't know that was also possible. Better than doing it by hand :) (+1)

Comment: Just tried it out and it didn't help either. As I mentioned I really think that it is timing issue. Generate.php is a file which contains same information until it gets runned again. And the js code calls it early. So it shows the oldest one before it generates the latest one. Because generating a new code and running it happens in same second, so I don't really know what to do since timeout function isn't working as well. :(

Answer (score 0):

It does wait 3 seconds before it gets the reply from `generate.php` it is more likely you have a cache problem.

If your website has server side caching enabled it will send the "old" php generated output instead of the new.

Append an increasing number or a tinestamp to the url like

```
"generate.php?v="+Date.now,
```

To force the server to always execute the php code and send you the current version.

Comment: Well, the problem is, the script mostly works well. But rarely it messing up, I really think that it is timing issue. Because generate.php creates a new code the JS runs it instantly. The generate.php is creating a code every 2 minutes, I have post the whole code if something is wrong.